# Javascript based HTML/CSS Lint

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any html/css checkers that are javascript based like JSLINT?

Comment: Any reason why js based checkers, what is wrong with w3c validators or CSS Tidy?

Comment: Just for a personal project, but I guess there aren't any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have some very specific requirement preventing it, your best bet here is to go the non-javascript route: [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

If your interest is in running it elsewhere, [it's source code is available](http://validator.w3.org/source/#getting).

Comment: Was looking for js-based, but since there are none I guess this will have to do.

Comment: There is an NPM package that will call the W3C validation service: https://github.com/nikestep/html-angular-validate - it's specific to validate HTML that uses AngularJS, but you can set `angular:false` if needed.  It's also available as a [grunt plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-angular-validate) or a [gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-angular-validate)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [HTML lint](http://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmllint.js) in Javascript recently, to be used together with [HTML minifier](http://kangax.github.com/html-minifier/) ([source is on github](http://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/src/htmlminifier.js)). It's based on a tweaked version of Resig/Arvidsson HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

### **Updated Info**

- [CSSLint](https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint) - Javascript based linter for CSS. Works on Rhino, Node.js,
- [CSSLint for Windows Script Host](http://jslint-for-wsh.googlecode.com/files/csslint-wsh.js)  - a modified version that works on WSH

Sample error message from the latter:

```
C:\dev\html>cscript //E:JScript c:\users\dino\bin\csslint-wsh.js --format=compiler style\basic.css

CSSLINT
style\basic.css(5,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h1) has already been defined.
h1           { font-size: 20pt }
style\basic.css(6,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h2) has already been defined.
h2           { font-size: 18pt; font-weight:bold; color: navy }
style\basic.css(7,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h3) has already been defined.
h3           { font-size: 16pt; font-weight:bold; color: #483d8b;}
style\basic.css(8,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h4) has already been defined.
h4           { font-size: 14pt; font-weight:bold; color:#C71585; margin-bottom:2px; }
style\basic.css(9,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h5) has already been defined.
h5           { font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold; color:#6495ED; margin-bottom:2px; }
style\basic.css(10,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h6) has already been defined.
h6           { font-size: 10pt; font-weight:bold; color:navy }
style\basic.css(12,1) CSSLINT: warning: Element (td.head) is overqualified, just use .head without element name.
td.head      { font-size: 12pt; color: #c71585;   font-weight: bold; }
style\basic.css(39,4) CSSLINT: warning: Broken box model: using width with padding.
   width: 48%;
style\basic.css(44,4) CSSLINT: warning: Broken box model: using width with border.
   margin: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0;
```

Example when used within Emacs with flymake:

[image]

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the link to the version of CSSLint that's easy to get working in Windows! I fumbled with Node.js for a while but gave up after it started reporting it was running out of memory parsing an 80k *.css file.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Inspector is a JavaScript HTML validator that can run in the browser or Node: https://github.com/philipwalton/html-inspector

It is the same validator CodePen uses.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started using [grunt-html](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-html) after several hours of debugging only to have been missing a closing bracket `>` which caused my html-minifier to hang.

I'm not sure it's perfect, nor do I expect it to be 100% compliant with W3C standards.  It does however help catch syntax / simple errors.

I have also came across a W3C varian,t [grunt-html-validation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-validation), of it as well.